Code does not stop at breakpoint in an exterior function in R
I am back to R after few years of absence. I want to use the breakpoints that do work in the main script as intended but not when the breakpoints is in an exterior function.
I created this simple piece of code just to visualize the issue.
In main.R I have these lines:
source("adding_numbers.R")

total_number <- adding_numbers(1, 2)
total_number2 <- adding_numbers(3, 4)
total_number3 <- adding_numbers(5, 6)

print(c(total_number,total_number2, total_number3))

The adding_numbers function is in the file adding_numbers.R and contains :
adding_numbers <- function (number1, number2)
{
  added_number <- number1 + number2
  z <- added_number + number1
  return(added_number)
}

In this post they do mention to source all files or use debug().
When I click on the button source, it does send the console in debug mode and works well when the breakpoints are in main.R, but when the breakpoints are in adding_numbers.R it does not stop at the breakpoints.
Using debug(adding_numbers) do make the code automatically enter the function, but again does not stop at specific breakpoints.
What am I missing here?
Thank you a lot.

I think calling source() from main.R is the problem.  That replaces the definition of adding_numbers that has the breakpoint set with a new copy of the function, and RStudio doesn't have a chance to re-set the breakpoint before you call it.
So you should call source("adding_numbers.R") first, then set a breakpoint, then execute your main code.
Alternatively, you could use the base function setBreakpoint("adding_numbers.R#3") to set a breakpoint on line 3 of that file.  This needs to happen after you source the file, and before you call the function.

Hi, thank you for responding. When I go to adding_numbers.R and click on source, I can see in the command line  debugSource("~/OneDrive - unige.ch/Sandbox/adding_numbers.R", echo=TRUE) running the lines from main.R allows me to stop at the breakpoints set in adding_number.R.

setBreakpoint("adding_numbers.R#3") opens a Traceback panel in Rstudio, and this time I do not see the green arrow pointing in the line of the "file" panel.

Finally, debugSource() can do the trick I want, but what if I have lots of functions if feels messier to add debugSource() every single time instead of a quick red dot click?

Sounds like you should move away from sourcing files directly, and create a proper R package. that's the normal way to organize collections of functions in different files.
